# Trouble getting Gradle to build Android L "Error: Found item Style/AppTheme more than one time"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

I am currently trying to create an Android app using the Android L SDK version.
However, when trying to build my project using Gradle, I run into the following error:

**"Error: Found item Style/AppTheme more than one time"**

Which points to my res/values-v21/styles.xml

I know that in res/values/styles.xml there is a style "AppTheme" already defined, but as far as I know I was following the Android developers guide on using Android L. Perhaps someone can help me:

Here is my:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
   buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mayuonline.ribbit"
    minSdkVersion 'L'
    targetSdkVersion 'L'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="resume.kelseyhrubes" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="L" android:targetSdkVersion="L"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
            <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
            <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
            <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme">@color/primary

        @color/primary_dark

        @color/primary_light
    </style>
</resources>
```

I apologize for the bad formatting, I hope everything is readable. 
If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please let me know. I just want to make an app with that sweet material design.

Comment: Like the error states, you have AppTheme defined twice in values-v21/styles.xml. Remove one of them.

Comment: Ahh of course! I'm not sure why I didn't notice that.